# Why does react-bootstrap Body Text (Card.text) show outside the box

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, frontend, react-bootstrap

I am trying add react-bootstrap card on my page. Ever element stays within the card EXCEPT the Card.text. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';


function ContactCards() {
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: '22rem' }}>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src="https://static.marham.pk/assets/images/home-new/specialities/derma.png" />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>Dr.Khan</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>
          Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
          bulk of the card's content.
        </Card.Text>
        <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default ContactCards;
```